# Do you need a neural network (keras) to use a classifier (sklearn)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I have a question regarding machine learning. I have coded a neural network in keras and I used a few sklearn classifiers after the neural network is complete. My question is are they related in one way or another?

Does the neural network directly affect the classifiers results? If i adjusted it would it affect my %s?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve,confusion_matrix, classification_report,auc
import sklearn.metrics as metrics
import seaborn as sns
import warnings
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle

from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

#Normalize Data
heart_data = pd.read_csv('data1.csv')

heart_data.head()
y = heart_data.target.values
x_data = heart_data.drop(['target'], axis = 1)
x = (x_data - np.min(x_data)) / (np.max(x_data) - np.min(x_data)).values
n_cols = x.shape[1]

#Splitting Data
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)




def regression_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    #inputs
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(n_cols,)))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='sigmoid')) # activation function
    model.add(Dense(1))

    # compile model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
    #loss measures the results and figures out how bad it did. Optimizer generates next guess.
    return model


# build the model
model = regression_model()
print (model)
# fit the model
history=model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test,y_test), epochs=100, batch_size=10)



#K Nearest Neighbor

neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=6)
neigh.fit(x_test, y_test)
y_test_pred = neigh.predict(x_test)
print("Test Accuracy of KNN Algorithm: {:.2f}%".format(neigh.score(x_test,y_test)*100))
print('KNN Teacher Classification report \n',classification_report(y_test, y_test_pred))
print ("The KNN AUC Score is: ",roc_auc_score(y_test, y_test_pred))

with open('knearest_teacher', 'wb') as k:
    pickle.dump(neigh, k)

#Support Vector Machine

svm = SVC(random_state = 1)
svm.fit(x_test, y_test)
y_test_pred2 = svm.predict(x_test)
print("Test Accuracy of SVM Alg orithm: {:.2f}%".format(svm.score(x_test,y_test)*100))
print('SVM Teacher Classification report \n',classification_report(y_test, y_test_pred2))
print ("The SVM AUC Score is: ",roc_auc_score(y_test, y_test_pred2))

with open('supportvector_teacher', 'wb') as s:
    pickle.dump(svm, s)

#Random Forest

rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 1000, random_state = 1)
rf.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_test_pred3 = rf.predict(x_test)
print("Random Forest Algorithm Accuracy Score : {:.2f}%".format(rf.score(x_test,y_test)*100))
print('Random Teacher Forest Classification report \n',classification_report(y_test, y_test_pred3))
print ("The Random Forest AUC Score is: ",roc_auc_score(y_test, y_test_pred3))

with open('randomforest_teacher', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(rf, f)

#Naive Bayes

nb = GaussianNB()
nb.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_test_pred4 = nb.predict(x_test)
print("Naive Bayes Algorithm Accuracy Score : {:.2f}%".format(nb.score(x_test,y_test)*100))
print('Naive Bayes Teacher Classification report \n',classification_report(y_test, y_test_pred4))
print ("The Naive Bayes AUC Score is: ",roc_auc_score(y_test, y_test_pred4))

with open('naive_teacher', 'wb') as n:
    pickle.dump(nb, n)
```

I am new to machine learning if it was not obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simplest terms, a neural nets are just a subset of machine learning models. As you've shown in your code provided, each can be trained and used independently. Note in your code, you don't use the output of your keras model in any of the other models, so no, it has no bearing on the other models

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. Your neural network is based on Keras. Your classifier is based on Sklearn. It's like does python related Java Script. They are both codes, but they are concurrent.

They are totally independent systems, you can delete one and the other one will still function unless the second one's data is based on the first one's result.

Hope this helped you.